# Ordering the contents of a Django filter dropdown control

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-filters

I have a Django filter, which works as expected allowing filtering of a List by selecting items in a dropdown control, but when it is rendered, the dropdown control items are in the order they were entered into the database, which is also to be expected.

However, this is not user friendly as it's really difficult to find the desired item. I'm trying to figure out how to sort the list of items displayed in the dropdown control (composer) in alpha order. Any help would be appreciated as I'm a novice with all of this.  The Filter code is below. I think I may need to manipulate a widget but not sure...

```
class PieceFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Piece
        fields = ['composer', 'instrumentation']
        exclude = ['title', 'description',
                   'study_notes', 'score_file', 'purchase_from', 'genre']
```

The filter renders two dropdown controls for filtering: 'composer' (which needs to be in alpha order) and 'instrumentation'.  On the template, the following code renders a button to search on the chosen items from the dropdown controls.

```
 <form method="get">
    {{myFilter.form}}
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
```

The view being used:

```
def library(request):
    pieces = Piece.objects.all().order_by('composer__name', 'instrumentation')

    p = Paginator(pieces, 10)

    print('NUMBER OF PAGES')
    print(p.num_pages)

    page_num = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    try:
        page = p.page(page_num)
    except EmptyPage:
        page = p.page(1)

    myFilter = PieceFilter(
        request.GET, queryset=pieces)
    pieces = myFilter.qs

    piece_count = pieces.count()
    context = {'myFilter': myFilter,
               'piece_count': piece_count, 'pieces': pieces}
    return render(request, 'video/library.html', context)
```

Comment: Is `Piece.composer` a `ForeignKey`? Could you add default ordering to the composer model?

Comment: Yes, Piece.composer is a ForeignKey.  I don't known how to add default ordering to the composer model but I will search for that - thanks

Comment: It didn't work.  I already have the list ordered by composer.  It is the default filter dropdown control list of values that needs to be ordered

Comment: @IainShelvington My apologies!  It did work perfectly by adding default ordering to the Composer model.  I stupidly added it to Pieces and wondered why it didn't work.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For custom ordering, you may use *ModelChoiceFilter*

Documentation: https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html#modelchoicefilter

```
from django_filters import ModelChoiceFilter

class PieceFilter(FilterSet):

    composer = ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=Composer.objects.all().order_by('name'))

    class Meta:
        model = Piece
        fields = ['composer', 'instrumentation']
```